Platform for negotiations, correct wording and closing “blank spots”
Continuing this topic: Potential employer promised to give an answer but has not yet responded
This is a great chance for me and I don’t want to miss it.  Therefore, I plan to answer as quickly and as best as possible.  I received the following message:
Name, hello!
I apologize for some delay in response.  Some of the days were weekends, some of them were spent thinking about things.
Our laboratory has 2 main directions.  The first is fundamental and theoretical physics (including related areas such as processing data from space experiments).  The second is work in the field of creating space scientific equipment (design, independent production of optical-mechanical units, development of electronics - detector units and on-board computers).  Plus a lot of paperwork - writing research papers, experimental design, operational documents, all sorts of programs and methods, etc.  My experience shows that it is almost impossible to work in the first direction without a basic physical education.  There were attempts, but they were all unsuccessful.  The second direction is closer to you, but I didn’t find a direct match either.  Besides, I don’t really understand how it can be used to work remotely.
Maybe then I’ll suggest turning the situation around.  Maybe, based on these areas, you yourself will evaluate where you could be most useful, and also write down your wishes regarding the format of the work.
Alternatively, we periodically carry out work on various projects (including this year), and it would be possible to discuss some kind of trial one-time contract.
Sincerely,
Dr.  Surname.
My arguments:

I will not refuse to receive additional education if necessary.

Processing of experimental data - a structured set of numbers, and it does not matter how they were obtained.  I can master, if not interpretation, then the tools for processing.

My thesis was devoted to the development of mechatronic instruments and devices for tracking the Sun.  Close to the laboratory profile.

Have experience in writing publications, grant reports, and technical documentation.

Paperwork, calculations, modeling, control systems, finite element analysis, 3D models - everything is done on a computer.


I would like to get some advice and learn how to improve my argumentation, position my arguments and close the “blind spots” in the negotiation, increasing the chances of success?
I will be glad and grateful!

With all due respect: your blind spot is not recognising when you are throwing good money (time) after bad.

@PhilipKendall What do you have in mind?

Do nothing about this job. Find a different one.

@PhilipKendall why?

Because the response you got is a very politely phrased "please go away".

@PhilipKendall What if not?  I'd try it.

@dtn - I would agree with other conclusions, they did not select you, and nothing you say at this point likely will change their mind.  However, I wouldn't want to work for anyone (or with anyone), who said so many words to say basically nothing. The paragraph you quoted, is a rambling set of words, that says basically nothing.

@dtn since you seem to want to be in a science field, I'd say go for it, getting your foot in the door is the hardest part. Getting your foot in the door while not stepping on someone's shoe is also important in this case, which is what you seem to be doing.

This reminds me why providing direct and specific feedback to failed applications is not always a good idea.

This answer reduces to "I honestly don't see where and how we can use you. You don't have the needed background and we don't have a job for a remote worker. If we missed something, let us know; otherwise better luck elsewhere and feel free to contact us again in a few years if/when you have acquired the right education and experience."
Unless there is an extremely good reason that you want to work with this specific group, trust their evaluation and look elsewhere. They have given you a fact-based response; you can't argue with facts. Saying you plan to learn is not a reason for them to hire you before you have learned. Enthusiasm by itself is not sufficient.
There are many job offerings. Don't become overly attached to any one. Most of your applications will be declined; accept that and move on. Even more will fail if you continue applying for jobs where you are not a good fit. Step back, do a serious evaluation of what your actual skills are, recognize that most employers DO NOT want to hire remote workers, and apply only to those where you really are a strong candidate, rather than wasting time applying to ones where you have no chance of acceptance.
